# Getting the following error: Another topology activation is in progress

Tags: search, powershell, search-express, topology

I am using Search Server Express 2010. I am creating Search application using PowerShell scripts.

After creating crawl and query components, i am activating them.

First activating crawl component

```
$crawlTopology = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlTopology -SearchApplication $searchApp | where {$_.CrawlComponents.Count -gt 0 -or $_.State -eq "Inactive"}
if($crawlTopology -eq $null)
{
    throw "Unable to find the crawl topology for Search application $SearchAppName."
}
$crawlTopology | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlTopology -Active -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err
if ($err -ne $null)
{
    throw $err
}
while ($true) 
{
    $ct = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlTopology -Identity $crawlTopology -SearchApplication $searchApp
    $state = $ct.CrawlComponents | where {$_.State -ne "Ready"}
    if ($ct.State -eq "Active" -and $state -eq $null) 
    {
        break
    }
    #Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Waiting on Crawl Components to provision..."
    Start-Sleep 2
}
# Need to delete the original crawl topology that was created by default
$searchApp | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlTopology | where {$_.State -eq "Inactive"} | Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlTopology -Confirm:$false
```

Then I am activating query component.

```
$queryTopology = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryTopology -SearchApplication $searchApp | where {$_.QueryComponents.Count -gt 0 -or $_.State -eq "Inactive"}   
if($queryTopology -eq $null)
{
    throw "Unable to find the query topology for Search application $SearchAppName."
}
$queryTopology | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryTopology -Active -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err
if ($err -ne $null)
{
    throw $err
}
while ($true) 
{
    $qt = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryTopology -Identity $queryTopology -SearchApplication $searchApp
    $state = $qt.QueryComponents | where {$_.State -ne "Ready"}
    if ($qt.State -eq "Active" -and $state -eq $null) 
    {
        break
    }
    #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Waiting on Query Components to provision..."
    Start-Sleep 2
}
# Need to delete the original query topology that was created by default
$searchApp | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryTopology | where {$_.State -eq "Inactive"} | Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryTopology -Confirm:$false
```

When i call query component activation, I am getting the following error:

> Another topology activation is in progress. Please wait until it is finished and try again

This is not happening everytime. Only happens few times. I am already checking for Topology status before proceeding. What other steps can i add to make sure that I don't get this error. Is there any job that i can check?